# How to schedule task every second Monday and given hour in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

Is there any way to schedule a task in Spring so it runs every other Monday at a given hour (say, midnight)? I know running the task every Monday at midnight using cron would look like that `0 0 0 * * MON` but it gets kinda obscure for me how to handle the "every **other**" Monday.

To be clear: if I deployed my application on Sunday 06.06.2021, I'd like the task to run on midnight 07.06.2021, 21.06.2021, 05.07.2021

Would something like `0 0 0 * * MON/2` work? Or should I take a different approach, maybe using something different than cron?

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No,Cron doesn't have such things in JAVA .It has some kind of workaround in linux and unix machines , but not in java.

But you can programmatically achieve it by using weeks of month.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       if(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) % 2 != 0) {
             //execute job
       } else {
             //not execute job just skip operation
       }
```

The above code executes for all odd weeks of a month.Let's say a particular month has 5 weeks , this will run for 1,3 and 5 of that month and will again run on 1st week of next month.

If you badly want it to run only twice a month , use can block it by checking if the week of month is grater than 4 and block it. (* I haven't checked it , give it a try)

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       if(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) % 2 != 0 && !c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)>4) {
             //execute job
       } else {
             //not execute job just skip operation
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I most likely will just do it in code instead of cron expression but the snippets you posted don't do what I'm looking for - if there's a month with 5 Mondays, I'd like my job to run on 1st, 3rd, and 5th Monday of that month and then on 2nd and 4th of the next one.

Comment: Yes, That would be the issue , because mine will run on 1st,3rd and 5th of first month and will again run on 1st of next month.  All the best